# dc.js pie chart sum example

Tags: crossfilter, dc.js

I have records like this :

```
{
{"Pass": "10", "Fail": "20", "Untested": "40"}
{"Pass": "20", "Fail": "40", "Untested": "50"}
{"Pass": "30", "Fail": "50", "Untested": "60"}
...
}
```

Obviously, total = pass + fail + untested. I want to sum up each of these values and then finally show a pie chart using dc.js that shows total Pass, total Fail, total Untested. I couldnt find a good example.

In the example below, each record is converted to a binary loss/gain value. Then the pie chart shows the aggregated loss/gain. I need to aggregate at the collection level, not individual record level. How can I do that ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Ref:

http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmUf9/)

The trick is to modify your input data, so that you can create an dimension for all records on the result. So the data should look like this:

```
[{"result":"Pass","value":"10","_id":0},
{"result":"Fail","value":"20","_id":0},
{"result":"Untested","value":"40","_id":0},
{"result":"Pass","value":"20","_id":1},
{"result":"Fail","value":"40","_id":1},
{"result":"Untested","value":"50","_id":1},
{"result":"Pass","value":"30","_id":2},
{"result":"Fail","value":"50","_id":2},
{"result":"Untested","value":"60","_id":2}]
```

I did this using a new js library I just created called [melt](https://github.com/jrideout/melt.js), but it would be fairly simple to duplicate the same logic yourself. Also here is another example in a recent [user list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/PSx_X5QPgXw).