# Partial Sums with DC.JS/Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, dc.js

I have a data set set up with the following structure:

> Q, FY, Name, Category, SubCategory, total, part1, part2, part3 
>   q1, 2005, proj1, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q1, 2005, proj2, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q1, 2005, proj3, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q1, 2005, proj4, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q2, 2005, proj1, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q2, 2005, proj2, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q3, 2005, proj11, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q4, 2005, proj12, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25 
>   q4, 2005, proj5, cat1, subcat1, 100, 25, 50, 25

I've been able to sum the totals according to the quarter within a fiscal year, and total the amounts according to the category, and was able to render this data to the graphs. 

 What I'm currently interested in, but having trouble with grasping, is how to loop through the part1, part2, part3 columns and obtain the sums of those columns then render them as a barchart with each column representing itself as it's own bar.. My goal is to be render a bar chart of the partial sums, then be able to adjust the totals according the filters on selected time frames or particular categories. 
Any advice on how I could go about this? 
 Is it necessary to create a dimension for each column then sum the total according to that dimension, or is it just a matter of iterating through the columns with a loop? 
 i.e. looking to render a chart along the lines of this.. each column name is listed as an individual bar

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at my response to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880437/329215). In short, you need to format your data to look like this:

```
Q, FY, Name, Category, SubCategory, part
q1, 2005, proj1, cat1, subcat1, part1, 25
q1, 2005, proj2, cat1, subcat1, part2, 50
q1, 2005, proj2, cat1, subcat1, part3, 25
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jrideout/daaac/

Comment: I see what you did with melt.js.. I'm going to give that a try. Thanks for the help!

Comment: so how do you get it to rearrange your data from a csv? I was able to parse it on a hardcoded dataset, but when I attempt to read a csv file from within d3.csv, my array is coming up empty

Comment: It works just fine on the values returned by d3.csv. I'd suggest you view the output of d3.dsv to double check your data looks like you think. Can you post an example somewhere to help pinpoint the issue?

Comment: How were you able to melt the data while keeping the crossreference to the other variables? From what I can see with melt, it will melt all the columns.

Comment: I'm very interested by melting only some columns, but I didn't manage with melt.js
Is anyone has found a solution ?